# Как задать константе hex цвета выбранного пользователем

Tags: java, color

Собственно, какой инструмент использовать?

Хотелось бы получить ссылки на русскоязычные мануалы и примеры. Гуглом пользовался - ничего путного не нашел. Или не так гуглил. Нагуглил лишь `JColorChooser`.